# error for sysdatetime()

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_movierentaldb |
+-------------------------+
| MEMBERSHIP              |
| PRICE                   |
| RENTAL                  |
| movie                   |
| video                   |
+-------------------------+

mysql> describe rental
    -> ;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RENT_NUM  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| MEM_NUM   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Hello stackoverflow community,
I have an issue when creating a table in mysql, I am trying to enter :

```
alter table RENTAL add RENT_DATE datetime default SYSDATETIME();
```

and I am getting a syntax error.

the reason I did not enter when creating the table because I had the same syntax issue when trying to enter it in the create table command:

```
CREATE TABLE RENTAL (
RENT_NUM     int PRIMARY KEY,
RENT_DATE   DATE DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
MEM_NUM int CONSTRAINT RENTAL_MEM_NUM_FK REFERENCES MEMBERSHIP);
```

I had the same issue with the constraint MEM_NUM but when I entered the following command it was able to create the constraint:

```
alter table RENTAL add foreign key (MEM_NUM) references
MEMBERSHIP(MEM_NUM);
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SYSDATETIME()' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
alter table RENTAL add RENT_DATE datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns. [See Section 12.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

[DOCs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the issue. Is there different formats of the current timestamp for example up to the millisecond  or second and so forth.

Comment: Yes there is but they are also limited. See it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html and for the different date types, here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: appreciate the time!